# Why does my program produce different results on Windows and Linux, about file reading with ifstream?

Tags: c++, ifstream

I have a program shown as follows.  For it I have several questions:

1). **Why does it produce different results on different platforms?**  I'll paste the screen-shots later.

2). **I'm using a fail() method to check if the "file.read()" failed.  Is this correct?**  I use fail() method because [this web page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/fail/) says this:

> The function returns true if either the failbit or the badbit is set. At least one of these flags is set when some error **other than reaching the End-Of-File occurs** during an input operation.

But later I read this page about istream::read() [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/read/).  It says the eofbit and failbit would always be set at the same time.. **Does this mean that a normal EOF situation would also result in that fail() returns true?  This seems to conflict with "other than reaching the End-Of-File occurs"..**

Could anyone help me clarify how I am supposed to use these methods?  Should I use bad() instead?

### My program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

#ifdef WIN32
char * path="C:\\Workspace\\test_file.txt";
#else
char * path="/home/robin/Desktop/temp/test_file.txt";
#endif

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    ifstream file;

    file.open(path);
    if (file.fail())
    {
        cout << "File open failed!" << endl;
        return -1;  // If the file open fails, quit!
    }

    // Calculate the total length of the file so I can allocate a buffer
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    size_t fileLen = file.tellg();
    cout << "File length: " << fileLen << endl;
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    // Now allocate the buffer
    char * fileBuf = new (std::nothrow) char[fileLen+1];
    if (NULL == fileBuf)
        return -1;
    ::memset((void *)fileBuf, 0, fileLen+1);    // Zero the buffer

    // Read the file into the buffer
    file.read(fileBuf, fileLen);
    cout << "eof: " << file.eof() << endl
         << "fail: " << file.fail() << endl
         << "bad: " << file.bad() << endl;
    if (file.fail())
    {
        cout << "File read failed!" << endl;
        delete [] fileBuf;
        return -1;
    }

    // Close the file
    file.close();

    // Release the buffer
    delete [] fileBuf;

    return 0;
}
```

### The test_file.txt content(shown with "vim -b". It's a very simple file):

[image: test_file.txt content]

### Result on Windows(Visual Studio 2008 SP1):

[image: Windows result]

### Result on Linux(gcc 4.1.2):

[image: Linux result]

Comment: cplusplus.com is not a good reference. It is full of bad examples (like testing the streams `fail()` member when it shouldn't) and factual errors. I recommend http://en.cppreference.com.

Comment: Try opening file in binary mode.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Does this mean that a normal EOF situation would also result in that fail() returns true? This seems to conflict with "other than reaching the End-Of-File occurs".

I recommend using a reference that isn't full of mistakes.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/fail says:

> Returns `true` if an error has occurred on the associated stream. Specifically, returns `true` if `badbit` or `failbit` is set in `rdstate()`.

And the C++ standard says:

> *Returns:* `true` if failbit or `badbit` is set in `rdstate()`.

There's no "other than end-of-file" thing. An operation that tries to read past the end of the file, will cause `failbit` to set as well. The `eofbit` only serves to distinguish that specific failure reason from others (and that is not as useful as one might think at first).

---

> I'm using a `fail()` method to check if the "file.read()" failed. Is this correct?

You should simply test with conversion to `bool`.

```
if(file) { // file is not in an error state
```

It's synonymous with `!fail()`, but it's more usable, because you can use it to test directly the result of a read operation without extra parenthesis (things like `!(stream >> x).fail()` get awkward):

```
if(file.read(fileBuf, fileLen)) { // read succeeded
```

You will notice that all read operations on streams return the stream itself, which is what allows you to do this.

---

> Why does it produce different results on different platforms?

The difference you're seeing between Windows and Linux is because the file is open in text mode: newline characters will be converted silently by the implementation. This means that the combination `"\r\n"` (used in Windows for newlines) will be converted to a single `'\n'` character in Windows, making the file have only 8 characters. Note how vim shows a `^M` at the end of the first line: that's the `'\r'` part. In Linux a newline is just `'\n'`.

You should open the file in binary mode if you want to preserve the original as is:

```
file.open(path, std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
```

Comment: +1 for _"I recommend using a reference that isn't full of mistakes."_

Comment: FTR, while I find cppreference.com generally better than cplusplus.com, I don't intend to say that is has no mistakes at all. The main difference is that, being a wiki, we can actually *fix* the mistakes in it. And the ultimate reference is the standard.

Comment: With regards to the use of `!fail()` and conversion to `bool`, the real difference is that using the stream itself as a boolean value is idiomatic.  It's what readers expect to see, and if you do something else, the reader will ask why.  (And technically, there is no conversion to `bool`.  There is a conversion to a pointer type, and an overload of `operator!`, which together allow the stream to be used as if it were a `bool`.)

Comment: @JamesKanze True. I'll add that the conversion was changed to an explicit conversion to `bool` in C++11.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Thanks for your explanations in detail!  You are right that I should have tried to open the file in binary mode!  Now I succeeded by doing so.  BTW: Thanks for your recommendation of cppreference as well!

Answer (score 2):

I guess, the problem here with the different execution is the DOS(Window) vs. UNIX text file convention.

In DOS, a line ends with `<CR><LF>`, and this is read/written together as `'\n'`. Thus, in Windows your file is at the end, but in UNIX not, since there is one character left.

Comment: this is really more of a comment

Comment: @sehe: No this is the answer. The problem lies in the conversion of the `end of line` sequence into a single character.

Comment: @LokiAstari It is a good hint, but I doubt the OP wasn't aware of the EOL difference. The real question was quite ostensibly "how should I deal with this in a platform-indepent fashion"?

Comment: @sehe Well, the OP stated two clear questions, you make up another. Maybe your question is more interesting, but it is not a question of the OP.

Comment: "Could anyone help me clarify how I am supposed to use these methods? Should I use bad() instead?" <--

Comment: @sehe That alludes to the second one. I answered the first.

Comment: @sehe: I think it is quite clear the OP does not know about the conversion of '\n' to end of line sequence.