# ifstream::tellg differs on MSVC2012 and gcc (mingw) when file has trailing newline

Tags: c++, iostream

**ANSWER**

Even though everything was compiled and run on windows, I completely forgot `tellg` behaves as an *unformatted* input function and cannot be used reliably in text mode which is why I see the discrepancy. See [std::basic_istream::tellg](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/tellg) for details.

**ORIGINAL**

The following extremely simple program is giving me different results with gcc 4.7.1 (mingw) and MSVC2012:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
int main()
{
    std::ifstream in("test.txt");
    int i;
    in >> i;
    std::cout << in.tellg() << std::endl;
}
```

The `test.txt` is as follows (**IMPORTANT NOTE:** There **is** a newline after the `1`)

> 1

MSVC Output:

> 1

gcc 4.7.1 (mingw) Output:

> 2

**Question**

I believe gcc is correct since `operator>>` should extract the newline, but am not certain. Which compiler is correct?

(**Note**: Both programs were compiled and run on windows).

**HEX of text file**

`31 OD OA`

If I create a linux-like line ended file, i.e. `31 0A`, MSVC outputs `0` and gcc outputs `1`.

Comment: Did you made sure via hex editor that the files under Linux and Win are the same ?

Comment: @ShmilTheCat: Everything was done on windows (including creation of the text file).

Comment: I see, what happens if you specify ios::binary in the ifstream Ctor ?

Comment: @pst: The newline is just the windows `OD OA`, i.e. `\r\n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following my comment, Please refer to this *excellent* post [Why does my program produce different results on Windows and Linux, about file reading with ifstream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817806/why-does-my-program-produce-different-results-on-windows-and-linux-about-file-r)

Comment: I'm using mingw. I didn't run anything on linux. Everything was compiled and run on the same platform (windows).

Comment: @JesseGood But your gcc uses stdlibc++, while MSVC uses their implementation, so I think the last paragraph of R.MartinhoFernandez's answer in that link still applies.

Comment: I just realized you are right. I expected mingw to interpret `\r\n` as `\n`, but it doesn't. Stupid mistake by me.

Comment: I remembered the answer now (see my edit), it's not that mingw does not follow windows conventions, it's that `tellg` behaves as an unformatted input function. `mingw` properly interprets `\r\n` as newlines. Thanks for the help in finding the answer.